# How to flip card one by one using scrollMagic

Tags: css, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm working on the animation using ScrollMagic and TweenMax.
The animation is that there are four cards are there, while the browser is scrolling down, each card flip one by one.

I've tried using each function to run the animation. but the problem was the triggers are in the same position so that the cards are flipping at the same time and also how to stop scrolling down while 4 cards are flipped?

here is my codepen
https://codepen.io/MachoBoy/pen/yGXNpg

```
// init scrollMagic
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
$('.card-wrapper').each(function(index){
    //build scene
    //console.log(this.children[0]);
    var flipCard = TweenMax.to(this.children[index], 1, {rotationY: -180});
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: this.children,
            offset: 400,
            duration: 300,
            triggerHook: 0.9
        }).setClassToggle(this.children[index], 'flipped').addIndicators().setPin('.card-wrapper').setTween(flipCard).addTo(controller);
})
```

Comment: I think TimelineMax has a delay attribute as well. So you can have four back-to-back events with delay.

Comment: @Quasar Thank you for the suggestion. I used TimelineLight to handle the problem but I could not implemented what I expected. still it is a good solution to use timeline . Thank you again!